# Bmesh selected faces list in modal operator is always a step behind

Tags: operator, bmesh

I am trying to get the list of the selected faces of a mesh using a modal operator which runs once a mouse button is pressed.

The issue I have is that the faces listed by the operator are always a step behind: if I have 3 faces selected, the operator is listing only 2 faces, and I have to press again the mouse button to get 3 faces listed. If I deselect a face, and then on screen I have two selected faces, the operator returns 3, but if I press again the mouse button I get 2, and so on.

This is an example of the code I am running:

```
import bpy
import bmesh

class ModalOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "object.modal_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Modal Operator"

    def __init__(self):
        print("Start")

    def __del__(self):
        print("End")

    def execute(self, context):
        context = bpy.context
        ob = context.edit_object
        me = ob.data

        bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(me)
        bm.faces.ensure_lookup_table()
        # list of selected faces
        selfaces = [f for f in bm.faces if f.select]
        if selfaces:
            print("%d faces selected" % len(selfaces))
        else:
            print("No Faces Selected")
        bm.free()
        
        return{'FINISHED'}

    def modal(self, context, event):
        if event.type in {'LEFTMOUSE', 'RIGHTMOUSE'}:
            obj = bpy.context.active_object
            if hasattr(obj, "type") and obj.type == 'MESH':
                self.execute(context)
        
        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}


    def invoke(self, context,event):
        self.execute(context)
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}
        
bpy.utils.register_class(ModalOperator)
```

I think that the issue may be in the *modal* definition where I return *PASS_THROUGH* instead of *RUNNING_MODAL*, but if I substitute *PASS_THROUGH* with *RUNNING_MODAL*, everything slows painfully down.

Any hint would be much appreciated.

Thank you,

Luca